# Take the first 10 characters of strings in a fastq file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, bioinformatics

am trying to select from a fastq file only the first 10 nucleotides of the reads:

```
Input:

@RONSP:03887:07268
GTAGTTATCTGAAAGGATGCATGGGAAAATTTCAATATTTTTGTATCTGTTGAGGACTTTTTTGTGAGTGACTATATGGTCAATTTTGGAGGATTTGGTACTGAG  
+  
69;::5:<<<<<<3<5<<<;:67717<=0@@9;:5::;;;?-;::::;;;5=;;5:888777)79:::;A;;;<<<<<7<::5:;=/706:5:<=3;5;;;<;;:  

@RONSP:09389:11828 
GTGTGTCTCTGTTCAGTTTCTGCTTCCAGGATCTGTCTCTTGGTGAGAGTGTGGTCTTGAAGTCTCCCAGTATTATTTTATGAGGTGCAATGTGTGCTTTGATCTTTAGCAAAGTGTATTTAATGAATGTGGCTGCTCTTGCATTTAGAGCATAGACATTCAGAATTGAG  
+  
8:::<<<<;<;;5;;:;;1;;?::4:5:;5888::<;<<<6<6<>?;;;;;DD7?=D5<;6<<=<>=4><==<5<<<<0<<<AA7<<;;5=>==<<:::0:<>666+599990999::<<193944.42421443668849:88919;;;;;<<;;<9928;=;5<4:9:  




Output:

@RONSP:03887:07268
GTAGTTATCT 
+  
69;::5:<<<  

@RONSP:09389:11828
GTGTGTCTCT
+  
8:::<<<<;<
```

Most of the tools trim starting from the end of the reads. But I need just the first 10 nucleotide of the reads.

Any idea is really appreciated.

Comment: What is the format of the output that you need and have you given this a try yourself first?

Comment: The output is always a fastq file. I would take the first 10 characters with: cut -c-10. But this should be done in steps like: 1st row not, 2nd yes, 3rd not, 4th yes... then pass to the other chunk and do the same. Basically i do not know how to split the file in chunk of 4 rows.. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sed -E '/^[^@+]/s/^(.{10}).*$/\1/' fastq
```

This will perform a substitution on all lines not beginning with `@` or `+`.  The substitution will replace the whole line with only the first 10 characters on the line.

Alternative formulation:

```
$ sed -E 's/^([^@+].{10}).*$/\1/' fastq
```

Answer (score 1):

awk

```
awk '{print /^@/ ? $0 : substr($0,1,10)}' file
```

bash

```
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    [[ $line == @* ]] && echo "$line" || echo "${line:0:10}"
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl

```
perl -lpe '/^[@+]/ or $_ = (unpack "A10A*")[0]'  your_fastq_file
```

## Sed

```
sed -ne '/^[^@+]/s/./&\n/10;P'  your_fastq_file
```

## Bash

```
dots10=$(yes '.' | head -10 | tr -d '\n')
while IFS= read -r line
do
   case $line in [!@+]* ) expr "$line" : "\($dots10\)";; * ) echo "$line";; esac
done < your_fastq_file
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into an issue when following the suggested solutions. Since quality values in fastq files may contain @ or + characters, these quality value lines may occasionally start with these characters.

My suggestion would be to only take the first 10 characters of every even line:

```
sed -E 'n; s/^(.{10}).*$/\1/' fastq
```